# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: ros, roslaunch, syntax

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

```
<launch>
   <!-- Camera Node -->
   <node name="$(arg camera_name)" pkg="uvc_camera" type="uvc_camera_node" output="screen" ns="$(arg camera_name)">
       <param name="device" type="string" value="$(arg device)" />
       <param name="camera_info_url" type="string" value="package://mcptam/calibrations/$(arg camera_name).yaml" />
   </node>
   <!-- camera_calibrator node -->
   <node name="camera_calibrator" pkg="mcptam" type="camera_calibrator" output="screen">
      <param name="cam_name" type="string" value="$(arg camera_name)"/>
      <param name="image_transport" type="string" value="compressed"/>
      <param name="image_topic" type="string" value="image_raw" />
      <param name="info_topic" type="string" value="camera_info"/>
  </node></launch>
```

this is my launch file but i got a message

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

which part is wrong??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224549/invalid-roslaunch-xml-syntax:-not-well-formed-(invalid-token)/) by [jamni](https://answers.ros.org/users/25658/jamni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your launch file.

"Line 1, column 0" is the first character in your launch file. I see a `<`, which should be valid, but perhaps you have a non-printing character in the file or something?

You can try to confirm by looking at a binary dump of the file (try `hexdump -C mylaunch.launch`).

You can also just create a new launch file, and retype the whole thing. (Don't copy/paste. there's a decent chance you'll copy the offending character into the new file)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jamni](https://answers.ros.org/users/25658/jamni/) on 2016-01-20**:
thanks for your answer :)
i try to confirm the binary dump, but there is no wrong things.
and i erase all the things and re-type the launch file(not copy and paste), it doesn't work too :(

there is another command like roslaunch?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-20**:
Try removing things from your launch file until it works, and then slowly re-add them until you identify the problem. The most basic launch file `<launch></launch>` should work (and do nothing).

**Comment by [sneibus](https://answers.ros.org/users/51953/sneibus/) on 2020-10-07**:
Im having the same issue where can i locate that roslaunch file ??

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may also occur if you are not referring to your launch file properly when you use the roslaunch command as it attempts to essentially run an empty file, for example:

```
roslaunch node_launch run
```

Instead of:

```
roslaunch node_launch run.launch
```

Where your launch file is called "run.launch".

---

Originally posted by [CWallbridge](https://answers.ros.org/users/28694/cwallbridge/) with karma: 101 on 2016-12-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nishanth97](https://answers.ros.org/users/33522/nishanth97/) on 2018-02-01**:
Thanks a lot! Totally forgot about it while using tab to auto-complete.